# Streaming MJPG with A-frame

Tags: aframe, mjpeg

I am new to A-frame and HTML in general. I want to stream a video to an object in A-frame for VR viewing. I'm currently streaming using `mjpg-streamer`. The below code just displays a white sphere even though http://IP:port/video is streaming the video (but will display an image like this [one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aframevr/sample-assets/master/assets/images/space/earth_atmos_4096.jpg)).

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="foo-component.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>

        <a-sphere src="http://IP:port/video" position="0 0 -4" radius="2" segments-height="53"></a-sphere>


    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Looking at this [example](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3734) makes me think I need to create a component which updates itself and include the component in the scene ( `<a-entity foo></a-entity>` but that doesn't show anything when I open the html... The component I created looks like this:

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
    schema: {
        width: { type: 'number', default: 10 },
        height: { type: 'number', default: 10 },
        depth: { type: 'number', default: 1 },
        color: { type: 'color', default: '#AAA' }
    },

    init: function () {
        var data = this.data;
        var el = this.el;

        this.loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

        this.geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(data.width, data.height, data.depth);
        this.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map: this.getImage()
        });
        this.material.needsUpdate = true;
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
        el.setObject3D('mesh', this.mesh);
    },

    tick: function (time, timeDelta) {
        this.mesh.material.map.img = this.getImage();
        this.mesh.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
    },

    getImage: function() {
        return this.loader.load("http://IP:port/video");
    }
});
```

Comment: were you able to fix this issue? if yes , please answer the question!